# reg exp: "if" and single "="

Tags: regex, grep

I need a regular expression (`grep -e "__"`), which matching all lines containing `if` and just one `=` (ignoring lines containing `==`)

I tried this:

```
grep -e "if.*=[^=]"
```

but `=` is not a character class, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `.*` may contain an `=`.

I'd suggest

```
grep -e "if[^=]*=[^=]"
```

If your goal is to find lines of code with an `if` containing an erroneous assignment instead of a comparison, I'd suggest to use a linter (which would be based on a robust parser instead of just regexes). The linter to use depends on the language of the code, of course (for example I use [this one](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign) in Javascript).

Comment: You need to exclude through to the end of the line. Without anchors, `grep` will return a match if there is a way to match somewhere within a line. `'if[^=]*=[^=]*$'` and maybe add something to also exclude matches with `=` somewhere before the `if` (not clear from the question whether this is necessary).